# Create Document attribute xml:lang

Tags: java, xml, dom

I need to add the attribute xml:lang="eng" on a Document Element.
I am using this code:

```
element.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", "xml:lang", "eng");
```

When the above method is executed, I am getting the following exception:

> org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is
>   made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with
>   regard to namespaces.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, is there another way to set this attribute?

**Stacktrace**

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
    org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.checkDOMNSErr(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.dom.AttrNSImpl.setName(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.dom.AttrNSImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createAttributeNS(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementImpl.setAttributeNS(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to "xml:lang='en'" .. does not throw an error in my debugger.

Comment: @user3447629: can you explain why by changing the way you have mentioned would not let debugger to throw any error/exception.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was quite simple, all I had to do was call element.setAttribute() without setting the namespace. This happens because XML is a default namespace, and it cannot be redefined / overwritten.